# How to represent the data of an excel file into a directed graph? Python

Tags: python, excel, networkx

I have downloaded California road network dataset from [Stanford Network Analysis Project](https://%20http://snap.stanford.edu/data/roadNet-CA.html). The data is a text file which can be converted to an excel file with two columns. The first is for the start nodes, and the second column is for the end nodes.

```
# FromNodeId    ToNodeId
       0           1
       0           2
       0          469
       1           0
       1           6
       1          385
       2           0
       2           3
      469          0
      469         380
      469        37415
       6           1
       6           5
      385          1
      385         384
      385         386
       3           2
       3           4
       3          419
       3          422
```

Now, how can I want to convert this data into an adjacency matrix or any other object for analysing the graph? For example for calculating degree distribution, clustering coefficients, etc.
I will be grateful for any help on how to represent this data into a graph using python and related libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your're looking for [`degree_distrubition`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.degree_histogram.html#degree-histogram) and [`average_clustering`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering.html) in [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx) :

```
#pip install networkx
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_edgelist("roadNet-CA.txt", nodetype=int, create_using=nx.DiGraph())

degree_distribution = nx.degree_histogram(G)
#[0, 8, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2]
clustering_coefficient = nx.average_clustering(G)
#0.0
```

[image]

Comment: **NB**: The SNAP provides a *python module* : http://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks. I thought that we first need to convert the data of txt file into an object and then use of `NetworkX` functions.

Comment: [`read_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html) accepts files as an input. You're welcome ;)